# From linux command line, how can I remove \n from a particular line to merge two lines together?

Tags: awk, sed, tr

Using the command line, how can I transform something like:

```
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line
extra bit
5 fifth line
6 sixth line
```

into, say:

```
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line; extra bit
5 fifth line
6 sixth line
```

The condition on which I would like to merge, is to remove any newline creating a line which does not start with a number.

I have seen answers to similar questions using the command-line tools `awk`, `sed`, and `tr`.

Comment: Could you please explain on condition part on which you want to merge the lines please? On what basis they should be merged? Is it if a line is not starting from digit then it should merge with previous line? Kindly confirm the same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for the question. To clarify, I'd like to specify a line number as the condition of what line to merge. E.g. line 5 in the example given.

Comment: Are the numbers part of the file?

Comment: @Cyrus yes they are

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 On second thought, it might be better to merge all lines that do not start with a number, rather than specifying by number each line to be merged.

Comment: Why couldn't `extra bit` be `127 foo bar` instead? If the answer is "it could be" then you can't merge based on whether the line starts with a number or not. I feel like there's probably some other clues in your real data about what should be merged (e.g. quotes) that you haven't shared with us yet. If you replace all the `first line` etc. strings with some **truly** representative values then it might be more obvious what we can do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far (which should stop your question from accumulating close votes). See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{ printf "%s%s", (NR == 1 ? "" : "\n"), $0; next} 
    {printf "; %s", $0} END { printf "\n"}' input
```

I'm not really sure what you want to do when the first line does not begin with a digit, and I'm making the assumption that starting with a digit is the characteristic you are looking for to combine lines.  Modify as needed.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed "4{N;s/\n/; /}" file
```

With GNU awk:

```
awk -v line=4 'NR==line{x=$0; getline; $0=x "; " $0}1' file
```

Output:

```
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line; extra bit
5 fifth line
6 sixth line
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.
Written and tested it in
https://ideone.com/xqk4si

```
awk -v line_num="5" '
FNR==(line_num-1){
  val=$0
  next
}
val{
  $0=val";"$0
  val=""
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** mentioning awk variable named line_num which has line number which OP wants to merge with its previous line. In main program checking condition if current line is just one lesser than mentioned line number of yes then create variable val and save that line. Then next condition checking if Val is SET then print previous line value semi colon and current line value and next will skip all further statements from there. `1` is way to print the current lines in `awk`

Answer (score 2):

> On second thought, it might be better to merge all lines that do not start with a number, rather than specifying by number each line to be merged.

Easy to do with `ed`:

```
printf "%s\n" '2,$g/^[^0-9]/-1s/$/; /\' '.,+1j' w | ed -s input.txt
```

Translated from `ed`'s rather cryptic commands: For each line that does not start with a digit (Skipping the first line because it has no previous one to merge with), add `;`  to the end of the previous line, and then join those two lines. Finally save the changed file.

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt
1 first line
2 second line
extra stuff
3 third line
4 fourth line
extra bit
5 fifth line
6 sixth line
$ printf "%s\n" '2,$g/^[^0-9]/-1s/$/; /\' '.,+1j' w | ed -s input.txt
$ cat input.txt
1 first line
2 second line; extra stuff
3 third line
4 fourth line; extra bit
5 fifth line
6 sixth line
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed, to join any number of lines not starting with a digit:

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n([^0-9])/; \1/;ta;P;D;' file
```